# How to enable tests based on spring boot profile?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

This is a similar but further question with [how to run/turn off selective tests based on profiles in spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39048171/how-to-run-turn-off-selective-tests-based-on-profiles-in-spring-boot).

I know the `@IfProfileValue` annotation provides the ability to enable test based on some conditions, but the properties it get are from `System.properties` and the `spring.profiles.active` is not in it.

I also know we can use `@ProfileValueSourceConfiguration` to customise the `ProfileValueSource` like below:

**Test**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ProfileValueSourceConfiguration(value = SpringProfileValueSource.class)
@IfProfileValue(name = "spring.profiles.active", value = "test")
public class MyTest {

    // some tests
}
```

**Custom ProfileValueSource**

```
public class SpringProfileValueSource implements ProfileValueSource {
    @Override
    public String get(String key) {
        Environment environment = StaticSpringContext.applicationContext.getEnvironment();

        return environment.getProperty(key);
    }
}
```

Since the `SpringProfileValueSource` will be created outside of Spring, so I created the following class to get Spring context:

**StaticSpringContext**

```
@Configuration
public class StaticSpringContext implements ApplicationContextAware {
    public static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        StaticSpringContext.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

However, seems all the properties check happens before Spring get started, so the `applicationContext` in `StaticSpringContext` **is actually null** when I use it in `SpringProfileValueSource`.

I thought it was a common situation to enable tests based on spring profiles, but I did many search and still don't know how to do it. Any ideas? With many thanks.

Comment: @Barath Thank you, but I think `@ActiveProfiles` will activate a profile for the test, and I want to enable the tests by using the values in spring.profiles.active