# Skip a specific test class during maven verify phase

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, junit

I have several test classes annotated with `@RunWith` and `@ContextConfiguration`.
I use the following dependencies in my maven SpringBoot project:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

and when I run `mvn clean verify` it executes all my test classes.

Now I have a specific test class that I want to **ignore** during the `verify` phase.

I tried to annotate it with `@ConditionalOnProperty`, so at the end the class is as following:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { RestTemplate.class, AvailabilityService.class, VerifyService.class,ConfirmService.class })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "it.alpitour")
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application-test.properties")
@ConditionalOnProperty("test.api.real.run")
public class ToIgnoreTest {
```

so I have added a property inside my `application-test.properties` file:

```
test.api.real.run=false
```

but the test is still executed and not ignored, during the `verify` phase.

How can I skip it?

Thanks

**edit**:

I prefer not to use `@Ignore` because I need at some point to run that specific test manually.
What I just need is to exclude that one when all the other tests are running.

Comment: Name the tests according to naming schema like unit tests `*Test.java` and integration tests like `*IT.java` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the annotation `@ignore` on your test class if you are using Junit 4 or else you could use the command as follows :

```
mvn -Dtest=\!YourTest* install
```

but I think since you are using springboot and not spring the better answer would be : [how to run/turn off selective tests based on profiles in spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39048171/how-to-run-turn-off-selective-tests-based-on-profiles-in-spring-boot)

Comment: Thanks but I cannot edit the command I use to run the tests, I'd prefer to work via code in this case

Comment: @Briston12 yeah i figured, I have updated the answer. I havent' tried this in springboot.

Comment: thanks again, I thought about `@Ignore` but at some point I need to run that test manually, so I cannot totally ignore it like that

Comment: ok great, the `@IfProfileValue` made the trick! Thanks for posting that answer